# regular expression to match strings start with a lowercase and continue with mixed cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a `regular expression` that says first letter not to be uppercase and the rest 0-19 characters mixed case.  This doesn't seem to do it.

```
!/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

Comment: put a `^` inside your first `[ ]` or do `[a-z]`

Comment: You want lower-case then mixed-case?

Comment: He posted this as a comment to my question further down below:

"I tried that it didn't help but I think there might be something besides my regx that's messing up my validation my function function validate_forename(field) { if (field === "") { return "No Forename was entered.\n"; } else if (!/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/.test(field)) { return "forename must begin with capital and be between 1 and 20 letters" } return ""; }"

I can't help him, so I thought I'd bring it further up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first letter lowercase, all the others lower-or-upper, you can do this:

```
/^[a-z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

Notice that you **cannot** just say `[^A-Z]` because that would allow non-alpha characters through, like numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One of many solutions is regex pattern

```
/^(?![A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/
```

...which reads: one to twenty letters with no uppercase in first place

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^A-Z]` instead of `[A-Z]`

`[^ ]` is the opposite of `[]`.It matches characters not contained within the brackests

So,it should be

```
/^[^A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

**OR**

simply use

```
 /^[a-z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
!/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

To:

```
/^[^A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried that it didn't help but I think there might be something besides my regx that's messing up my validation  my function  function validate_forename(field) {
  if (field === "") {
   return "No Forename was entered.\n";
  } else if (!/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{0,19}$/.test(field)) {
   return "forename must begin with capital and be between 1 and 20 letters"
  }
  return "";
 }

Comment: Hmm. I'm not entirely sure what it could be the. Copy what you just wrote and put it as an edit to your question, so more people can see and help you out. Sorry.